# Set up colours for Y label ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, subplot

How can I setup the colours for my following pic? I would like to get the same colour for all the points that refer to the same numbers (all points for `1`, one colour, all points for `2`, another colour...and so on) in all the subplots.

[image]

this is my code:

```
D = melt(Y2, id='Row.Names')
p5 = ggplot(D, aes(x=factor(Row.Names), y=value, group=variable, colour=variable))
p5 + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~variable, scale="free") +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach and next time please include a sample of your data. Using the group aesthetic element you can have same color. Here the code that can fit to your real data using a dummy dataframe (I have increased point size to see how colors are equal):

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
df <- data.frame(var=c(rep('Danceability',3),rep('energy',3),rep('key',3)),
                 value=rnorm(9,1,2),
                 id=factor(rep(c(1,2,3),3)))
#Plot
ggplot(df,aes(x=id,y=value,color=id,group=id))+
  geom_point(size=3,show.legend = F)+
  facet_wrap(.~var, scale="free")
```

Output:

[image]